# Given vec field $\vec{F}(x,y,z) = xy^3 \vec{i} + x^3y\vec{j}$ find line integral from $(0,0)$ to $(2,8)$ on path $y = 2x^2$ (possible textbook error)

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I am give the following problem:

> Given the vector field $\vec{F}(x,y,z) = xy^3 \ \vec{i} + x^3y\ \vec{j}$ find the line integral from $(0,0)$ to $(2,8)$ on the path $y = 2x^2$

My answer:

Along the curve we have

\begin{align*}
\overrightarrow{F}(x,y,z) &= \left< xy^3, x^3y \right>\\
\vec{r}(t) &= \left< t, 2t^2\right>\\
\\
\vec{F}(\vec{r}(t)) &= \left< 8t^7 , 2t^5 \right>
\end{align*}

Calculating the derivative of the parametrization,

\begin{align*}
\vec{r}'(t) = \left< 1, 4t \right>
\end{align*}

The dot product is given by

\begin{align*}
\vec{F}(\vec{r}(t)) \cdot \vec{r}'(t) &= \left< 8t^7 , 2t^5 \right> \cdot \left< 1, 4t \right>\\
&= 8t^7 + 8t^6
\end{align*}

So the line integral is

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}  8t^7 + 8t^6 \ dt &= \cdots \\
&= \frac{15}{7}
\end{align*}

The problem is that my answer differs from the textbook's. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

**Textbook's answer:** $\frac{2816}{7}$

Thank you.

Comment: It looks fine to me. (You just fixed the typo.)

Comment: Yes there was a typo, I just fixed that Ted, thank you.

Comment: Did you reach the same result as me?

Comment: I checked your work and it looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You integral range is wrong. It should be from 0 to 2 but not from 0 to 1.